# start-process with a special name, or handle to kill it

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

We have a number of node.js programes that all are created with powershell. We used the start-process to spawn the node.js executable in the background (node.exe).

We would like to give each one a different "handle" so that we can later use the powershell command stop-process to kill them. e.g. start-process -Name 'wServer'
The powershell script to kill, will be different than the one to start, and a different user might well use it.

I am stuck on how to identify each node.exe different. It is not the executable that is different but the path to the app.js

Here is how we start one of them:

```
$reg = Get-Item -Path "hklm:\SOFTWARE\us\EGPL\GeoLibrarian" 
$path = $reg.GetValue('LibrarianPath').ToString() 
$sixtyfour = [Environment]::Is64BitProcess

# Now start running Watson
$node = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
$arg = "app.js"
$dir = "$path\Watson"
start-process -WorkingDirectory $dir $node $arg
Write-Host "64-Bit Powershell: "$sixtyfour
Write-Host "PowerShell Version: "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Write-Host "Watson running in background"
```

right now, I can kill ones started with a unique window via this sequence, I don't think the ones started in powershell will have a window.

```
Write-Host "Kill watson task"
$watson = get-process | where-object {$_.MainWindowTitle -eq 'WatsonJS'}
Stop-Process -Id $watson.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One method is to use the `-PassThru` parameter, which causes `Start-Process` to return an object which can be used to control the process.  When you're done with the process, pipe the object to `Stop-Process` (or call the object's `Kill()` method)

In cases where you need to store the object across PS sessions, you can save the variable to an XML file using `Export-Clixml`.  Later, rehydrate the variable using `Import-Clixml`.

PS Session #1

```
$proc = Start-Process notepad -Passthru
$proc | Export-Clixml -Path (Join-Path $ENV:temp 'processhandle.xml')
```

PS Session #2

```
$proc = Import-Clixml -Path (Join-Path $ENV:temp 'processhandle.xml')
$proc | Stop-Process
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But I did not make it really clear. The script that starts the process will NOT be the one that kills it. Nor will it be the same user. Nor even the same day or week. So it is not possible to keep the information about the spawned task in powershell variable.

Comment: Updated the answer.  I use `Export-Clixml` to pass variables between PS instances.  Doesn't always work for super-deep objects, but I tested this just now and it killed the correct instance without affecting any others.